# HTML page scrollbar takes into account hidden content

Tags: html, css, primefaces

I'm using primefaces dataTable with 'scrollable' attribute.
And this table cause outer scroll bar to takes into account hidden content.

How can I avoid this behavior?

[image]

DataTable settings:

```html
<p:dataTable id = "userLayerSettingsTable" value="#{userSettingsView.layerSettingsTable}" var="settingLayer" style="margin-top: 10px"
             rendered="#{userSettingsView.layerSettingsTable.size() > 0}"
             emptyMessage="Записей не найдено"
             scrollable="true" scrollHeight="268" tableStyleClass="settings-table" rowIndexVar="numLayer">...
```

Comment: I'm not seeing this in my projects or the showcase. What PrimeFaces version are you using? And which browser and what version?

Comment: Primefaces 7.0
Chrome version 91.0.4472.106 (64bit)

Comment: I wonder if its related to this Chrome 91 issue? https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/7379

Comment: @Melloware if so, we would be able to replicate the issue with Chrome on the showcase

Comment: @Melloware potentially its related, but in my example it demonstrate another behavior.

By the way I have checked this problem in Mozila Firefox 84.0.1 and there is no such problem. Outer scrolling work well.

Comment: Can you please create a [mcve] using https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test?